# What's "Nusach Kafa"?

Tags: minhag, prayer-book, nuschaot

I saw yesterday that the [Crimean Jews](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/krimchaks) - which were an ancient kehillah - had their own nusach, called "Nusach Kafa" (נוסח כפא). I was wondering in what ways was this nusach unique? What special traditions/customs did they have? Note: There's a book called המחזור לכמנהג כפא: תולדותיו והתפתחותו in the National Library of Israel, but can only be accessed from there, and the library is closed these days.

Comment: https://ms-my.facebook.com/historiaolamit/posts/788218474666024 See note 1 at the end

Comment: Lots of communities have lots of strange customs. Are you looking for a list?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות a list would be best, but any info would be appreciated.

Comment: Every town always had there own customs. It's impossible to make a complete list. The idea that there is one nusach ashkenaz and one nusach sfard is an invention the last ~century

Comment: @DoubleAA Impossible to make a list of what was unique? And Crimea isn't a town...

Answer (score 7):

The only custom I've previously come across from that community (cited by Siddur Otzar Hatefillot, Volume 2, page 46) is that they had the custom to read Megillat Antiochus on Chanukah.

A quick search on through Otzar Hatefillot (using Otzar Hachochma) comes up with various other strange or interesting minhagim. Here are some:

- They added various adjectives to "Kulam Ahuvim" (p. 258)
- There are a bunch of significant changes to the Amidah (see pages 305, 313, 324-6, 330, 337-8, 340, 343, 345, 349, 357, 359, 364)
- They shortened Tachanun a bit (page 403)